# PS3 lost network whilst patching Injustice: Gods Among Us, and now won't re-download patch

Tags: ps3, technical-issues, injustice-gods-among-us

Recently I've encountered a problem. Well, it wasn't a problem at the beginning, but now my PS3 can't even start downloading a patch.

What happened step-by-step:

1. I booted my PS3
2. Started the game (*Injustice: Gods Among Us*)
3. PS3 asked if I want to download and install the update
4. I chose "YES" and waited
5. At around 84% (or so), my internet went down. When it was back up, PS3 wasn't able to continue the download, so it was still calculating(and adding) the time remaining.
6. After a while I turned it off (by holding power button)
7. Repeated steps 1-4 again
8. PS3 wanted to start downloading the new patch, but all over sudden it beeped a few times and rebooted itself.
9. Repeated steps 7 and 8 a few times
10. Deleted the game data to return the game back to version 1.00
11. Tried to install patch again - and got the same problem (as in step 8)

Since then I can't install a new patch on that game. I didn't try installing patches to other games, but I think that it shouldn't be a problem.

So the question is: how can I fix it?

Comment: Can't you download System Updates manually through your PC, and dump it onto a USB stick for updating?

Comment: @fbueckert I didn't think about it. But will System Updates fix that you think?

Comment: Oh, is it a game update, not a System Update?  I don't believe you can download and install game updates via USB.  Sorry, thought it was a System Update, because I just had to update my PS3 for the new Tales game.

Comment: Uhm. Try playing another game for a little while. Then try step 9 again? I have no idea what it might do but it's worth a shot?

And can you play the game offline?

Comment: @Reafexus yes, playing it offline is no problem. I just can't install the patch. Well, the download doesn't even start :/